# Date Time conversion in user timezone

Tags: java, android, sqlite, timezone, simpledateformat

I have certain date field of a record in **sqlite database** that is saved at certain format.

To convert this **date** column to a certain format, I did some date formatting and add it in an array `dbDates` with the following code-

```
SimpleDateFormat dateIn = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

dbDates.add(dateIn.format(formatter.parse("2013-12-16T02:00:00.000Z");
dbDates.add(dateIn.format(formatter.parse("2013-12-15T01:30:00.000Z");
```

The dbDates as printed in console is now in the following format -

```
Mon Dec 16 02:00:00 GMT+05:30 2013

Sun Dec 15 01:30:00 GMT+05:30 2013
```

**NOTE:** As noticed, `+05:30` is added at the end of each dbDate.

This caused a problem when I convert it to user timezone.

**So adding this line ----**

```
dateIn.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

**Changes the output to -**

```
Sun Dec 15 12:30:00 PST 2013
Sun Dec 14 12:00:00 PST 2013
```

**However, the correct output should be:**

```
Sun Dec 15 18:00:00 PST 2013

Sun Dec 14 17:30:00 PST 2013
```

So, there is +05:30 difference in the output. How to resolve that ?

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.Date class bundled with Java has no time zone defined inside the instance. Yet its `toString` method renders a string using the JVM's default time zone. I'll bet your JVM is set to an Indian time zone, given to +05:30.

This is one of many reasons to avoid using the java.util.Date/Calendar classes. They are notoriously bad in both design and implementation.

Immediately download for yourself a copy of the Joda-Time library. Use that for all your business logic and calculations.

In Joda-Time, a DateTime instance does indeed know its own time zone.

When necessary to deal with other classes, convert to a j.u.Date by calling the `toDate` method on a DateTime instance.

Search StackOverflow.com for `joda` to find many examples.

In Java 8, either continue using Joda-Time or switch to the new java.time.* classes defined by JSR 310. The new classes are inspired by Joda-Time but are entirely re-architected.